# aws-sdk-s3 PHP ListObjects fails when prefix doesn't exist in bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

We are using ListObjects with specific prefixes to return keys to process.  Some of the prefixes don't exist all the time. Our previous working environment was PHP 7.3 and aws-sdk 3.142.0 and the code worked as expected.  If the prefix has data the result would be parsed, if the prefix didn't exist it returned nothing without issue.  We have recently upgraded to PHP 8.1.8 and aws-sdk 3.231.8.  ListObjects returns the data as expected when the prefix exists, if the prefix doesn't exist the call fails and the code fails and it is not handled by the exception code. The below code processes the listObjects prefix acr/ and then fails on acr_processed/ because the prefix doesn't currently exist in the bucket.

Has anyone seen this or have a workaround? thank you in advance

```
$prefixarray = array('acr/','acr_processed/'); // NOTE: acr_processed/ doesn't exist
foreach ($prefixarray as $prefix) {
    $bucketName = 'abc';
    try {
        $objects = $s3->ListObjectsV2(['Bucket' => $bucketName,
            'Prefix' => $prefix
        ]);
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo "there was a S3 exception";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'there was an exception';
    }
    foreach ($objects['Contents'] as $contents) {
        echo $contents['Key'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Addressed, call it a workaround because the error 500 still returns if a prefix doesn't exist when you try and list it.  With these current versions of PHP and Asw-sdk.
To fix create a dummyobject in the prefix being listed prior to the listing of the prefix.  The process is HeadObject to see if the dummyobject is there, if not putObject in the prefix and then list the prefix.  The dummyobject will be returned but it is easy to skip when processing the list results.

```
$tagstring = 'status=placeholder';
$dummykeyName = $prefix . 'placeholder.prefix';
try {
    // head a s3 object:
    $result = $s3->headObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucketName,
        'Key' => $dummykeyName
    ]);
    // found
    $NoResults = 'no';
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    die('s3 Error:' . $e->getMessage());
} catch (Exception $e) { // placeholder.prefix was not found put it
    try {
        $s3->putObject(
            array(
                'Bucket' => $bucketName,
                'Key' => $dummykeyName,
                'ContentType' => 'text/xml',
                'Tagging' => $tagstring,
                'StorageClass' => $strgclass
            )
        );
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo 'there was an S3 exception ' . $dummykeyName . '<br>';
        $NoResults = 'yes';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'there was an exception ' . $dummykeyName . '<br>';
        $NoResults = 'yes';
    }
}
// get the list of objects from the bucket
try {
    $objects = $s3->ListObjectsV2(['Bucket' => $bucketName,
                                 'Prefix' => $prefix
                                ]);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
    echo "<tr><td>list-enduser error" . $e . "</td></tr>";
    $NoResults = 'yes';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'there was an exception';
    $NoResults = 'yes';
}
```